# Oracle SQL Command: Averaging one column

Tags: sql, oracle

3. Create a view named CONDO_FEES. It consists of two columns: the first is the square footage, and the second is the average fee for all condos in the CONDO_UNIT table that have that square footage. Use AVERAGE_FEE as the column name for the average fee. Group and order the rows by square footage.

a.  Write and execute the CREATE VIEW command to create the CONDO_FEES view.

This is the code I wrote:

```
CREATE VIEW CONDO_FEES AS
SELECT SQR_FT, AVG(CONDO_FEE) AS AVERAGE_FEE
FROM CONDO_UNIT
GROUP BY SQR_FT
ORDER BY SQR_FT;
```

This is the other that I tried:

```
CREATE VIEW CONDO_FEES (SQR_FT, AVERAGE_FEE) AS
SELECT SQR_FT, AVG(CONDO_FEE)
FROM CONDO_UNIT
GROUP BY SQR_FT
ORDER BY SQR_FT;
```

It is not averaging all of the condo's together. It's only averaging condo's with the same square footage. Example:

```
Sqr_ft    Average_fee
1100      300
550       150.5
300       100
550       150.5
500       130
```

Comment: So? What's the problem? Isn't that exactly what the requirement asks you to do?

Comment: Actually, this is my fault. I completely read the question wrong. I was trying to make it average all of the columns instead of just columns with that particular square footage.

Either way for future reference, if I wanted to do it in the way that it averages all condo fees as a whole and not just by square footage. How would that work? Taking out the group by?

Comment: If you want avg fee for all the condos irrespective of sqr foot size, remove group by sqr_ft, order by sqr_ft and sqr_ft from select clause